# Convert a string into different arrays based on certain characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string like this:

```
var string = "cat, dog/hat, car, fork/John, Jane";
```

There is no telling how many terms will be located between each forward slash "/" and some will have spaces " ". Each term is separated with a single comma ",".

The final output should look like:

```
array1 = ["cat_1", "dog_1"];
array2 = ["hat_2", "car_2", "fork_2"];
array3 = ["John_3", "Jane_3"];
```

I'm not really sure where to start with this since I'm fairly new to Javascript. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is this homework?

Comment: Not really, I'm self teaching and this was part of a challenge I set for myself. Just could not figure out a smart way to solve this after an hour or so.

Comment: You're not really self teaching, nor challenging yourself, if you are just asking without you providing any code you have tried with, and the problems you have encountered. Show us what you have done during that hour, and where you got stuck.

Comment: You may take a look at [string.split()](//mdn.io/string.split()), try something, and either solve your issue yourself, or come back with a less broad issue and an [mcve](/help/mcve).

Comment: Fair point, everyone; I should have posted some of my work and been more specific. I still appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const string = 'cat, dog/hat, car, fork/John, Jane';
const results = string.split('/')
.map((pair, i) => pair.split(',').map((single) => single +'_'+ (i+1)));
```

Now results have three arrays with values you wished for.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is ES6 code and may not run error-free in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

```
str.split('/')
```

Will split your example string into the following:

```
["cat, dog", "hat, car, fork", "john, jane"]
```

From there you can create new arrays by going through each string element in the array received from `split`. Hope that helps!